# Allowing child iframe to access specific javascript functions in the parent

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I need to be able to run unverified code safely in my app and need to reveal some functions to the iframe. The code written in the iframe will need some data from my site and I'm thinking the best way to do this may be through the child calling a function that then triggers the parent to make an ajax request. Is this feasible and/or the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally assume that an iframe can't talk to its parent directly; That would be like one tab being able to control another tab.

The best way to handle communication between two related iframes, especially across domains, is to use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). This allows you to configure events that listen for messages being passed and handle them as they arrive. It also provides control over which domains are allowed to send messages.

```
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(e) {
  console.log('received message', e.data);
}
```

Using this approach, you can pass data, trigger different actions with different messages, etc.

This is how the YouTube API works, allowing developers to load the video player in an iframe and still listen for playback events, pause videos, switch video sources, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this turned me onto the documentation I needed. Are you able to recommend any books/articles that go into this concept indepth?

Comment: Those MDN articles are about as in-depth as you can get. Message passing isn't a very complicated topic.

Comment: I meant more on the topic of running unverified code safely, building code platforms.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a discussion forum, it's for specific technical questions that have concrete answers. You can find that information elsewhere.